# Django internationalization in url patterns with parameters

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-i18n

I'm working with Django 1.6 and Python 3.4. I want to translate urls within parameters. For example:
/en/temperature/London/
to:
/fr/température/Londres/
but it doesn't work. Instead I obtain /fr/temperature/London/ . In urls.py "temperature" is hardcoded, "London" is value of parameters `city`. `treshold` is optional.
This url, without parameters, is translated correctly: /en/terms/ to /fr/mentions-légales/
After every change in django.po, I run compilemessage command, I reboot manually development server and flush browser cache.   What is wrong?

```
urls.py:
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('foo.views',
    url(_(r'^terms/$'), 'terms', name="terms"),
    url(_(r'^temperature/%(city)s(?:/(%(treshold)s))?/$') %{'city': city, 'treshold': treshold}, 'temperature', name="temperature"),
)
```

---

```
django.po
#: /urls.py:X
#, python-format
msgid "^temperature/%(city)s(?:/(%(treshold)s))?/$"
msgstr "^température/%(city)s(?:/(%(treshold)s))?/$"

msgid "London"
msgstr "Londres"

msgid "^terms/$"
msgstr "^mentions-légales/$"
```

---

```
{% load i18n %}
<a href="{% url 'temperature' city="London" %}">Link name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py you should have the line:

```
url(_(r'^temperature/%(city)s(?:/(%(treshold)s))?/$') %{'city': city, 'treshold': treshold}, 'temperature', name="temperature"),
```

Since this is the line you refer to in your django.po. There you search for temperature and replace it with température then

additionally you should use:

```
{% load i18n %}
<a href="{% url 'temperature' city=_("London") %}">Link name</a>
```

Which will tell Django to translate London as well.

You could also use 2 urls:

```
url(_(r'^temperature/%(city)s(?:/(%(treshold)s))?/$') %{'temperature': temperature, 'treshold': treshold}, 'temperature', name="temperature"),
url(_(r'^témperature/%(city)s(?:/(%(treshold)s))?/$') %{'temperature': temperature, 'treshold': treshold}, 'temperature', name="témperature"),
```

and in your html you can use:

```
<a href="{% url _('temperature') city=_("London") %}">Link name</a>
```

Comment: You are right: in urls.py "temperature" instead "température"; I've just edited my first post. Adding _(), but without space after "city=", I obtain /fr/temperature/Londres/: only "temperature" remains to be translated.

Comment: This has to do with the regex. I think your django.po can not handle regexes at the moment and does a string comparison. Since the threshol part is not there it does not match the string "^temperature/%(city)s(?:/(%(treshold)s))?/$"

Comment: I tried without "(?:/(%(treshold)s))?" but it doesn't solve the problem. Could this help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns ? '/en/news/category/recent/' is translated into '/nl/nieuws/categorie/recent/', but there isn't django.po file.

Comment: You can solve this if you use London as an optional parameter like they use slug=recent in this example:

url(_(r'^temperature/(?P<city>[\w-]+)/$') 'temperature', name="temperature"),

Comment: Because the "city" will be replaced by "London" and I think the string comparison fails on this since it is not equal

Comment: I should find the solution: `url(_(r'^temperature/(?P<city>[\w]+)(?:/(?P<treshold>[\w]+))?/$'), 'temperature', name="temperature"),` and msgid `"^temperature/(?P<city>[\\w]+)(?:/(?P<treshold>[\\w]+))?/$"
msgstr "^température/(?P<city>[\\w]+)(?:/(?P<treshold>[\\w]+))?/$"`

Comment: But I don't feel confident. I'll post complete solution, as soon as I understand the problem totally.

Comment: If I define a regex pattern and then use it in urlpatterns with `%s`, with or without name, translation doesn't work. Instead if I insert the regex pattern directly into urlpatterns translation works. Now problem is don't repeat everywhere same regex, especially more complex ones.